# R: how to use rbinom to generate deviates

Tags: r

```
rbinom(1000, size=74, prob=0.89)
```

I'm still a little rusty with the rbinom function. In the code above, I am generating 1000 observations of 74 trials, with the prob of success on each trial = 0.89. I want the deviates that I generate to be less than or equal to 74. How can I restrict the rbinom function to account for this? I'm getting, though rarely, deviates that are >= 74 from my code above, and that is causing problems in my program.

Comment: Your code is correct. I can not replicate the problem.

Comment: x=rbinom(1000, size=74, prob=0.89) and I try any(x>=74) and this sometimes returns TRUE

Comment: I tried `max(rbinom(1000000000, size=74, prob=0.89))` and it returned `74`. You should consider restarting your R session.

Comment: @Bonnie is there some reason that out of the 10 questions you've asked you have only *ever* accepted 1 answer and *never* cast a vote? Read [**the about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made **much** more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark or upvote it. You are **not** obliged to do so, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did help and helps to keep the site clean by marking questions as answered.

Comment: Consider reviewing your other questions and the answers you received there too. I see a lot of great ones. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will occasionally have some deviates that are equal to 74 hence `>=` may return `TRUE`. They will *never* be greater than 74 though because you only run 74 trials. Try `any( x > 74 )` instead.

```
set.seed(5895)
x <- rbinom(1000, size=74, prob=0.89)
table( x >= 74 )

# FALSE  TRUE 
#   999     1 

table( x > 74 )

# FALSE 
#  1000 

max(x)
# [1] 74
```

Any yes, I did have to go through a few `.Random.seed`'s before I found one that would give this result! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I found what was causing the problem. `x=rbindom(1000, size=74, prob=0.89)` and then I used the rnom function `rnorm(NNN, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))` and `rnorm` is the function that is outputting values > 74. Is there a way to stop it from doing so? Or perhaps I can remove those > 74 values after they've been generated. That might be of some help too.

Comment: @Bonnie Assuming you assign the output of the call to `rnorm` to an object called `x.norm`, then `x.norm[ ! x.norm > 74 ]`.